# How to substract a number in two columns in the given row in spreadsheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

```
=IF(ADDRESS(ROW(),4)="Long",VALUE(ADDRESS(ROW(),8))-VALUE(ADDRESS(ROW(),9)),VALUE(ADDRESS(ROW(),9))-VALUE(ADDRESS(ROW(),8)))
```

I want to perform `I - J` if the value in D is `Long`, I want to perform `J - I` if the value in D is `Short`. I want to do this for the current row

However, I get the following error:
`VALUE parameter '$I$2' cannot be parsed to number.`

Provided is a screenshot of my spreadsheet
[image]

I would appreciate help, since this is my first time working with spreadsheet formulas.

Comment: Direct use cell reference like `=I2-H2`.

Comment: Probably you want something like this: `=IF(D2="Long",I2-J2,J2-I2)`, or this `=ABS(I2-J2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ADDRESS** refers to the Address, (here **$I$2**) not the value (here **1.2**). If you want to keep this **ADDRESS** method, then try to use **INDIRECT**

`=IF(indirect(ADDRESS(ROW(),4))="Long",VALUE(indirect(ADDRESS(ROW(),8)))-VALUE(indirect(ADDRESS(ROW(),9))),VALUE(indirect(ADDRESS(ROW(),9)))-VALUE(indirect(ADDRESS(ROW(),8))))`

Comment: Nice! Obviously you could do a direct call as @Foxfire And Burns And Burns said earlier
   **=IF(D2="Long",I2-J2,J2-I2)** or **=ABS(I2-J2)** , but I guess this is not what you need